# Finding maximum error when interpolating polynomials

Tags: numerical-methods

Using the points (0,2), (1,4), and (2,8) suppose $f(x)=2^{(x+1)}$ is an approximation. What is the maximum error on [0,3]?

I know the error formula is $$\frac{f'''(\varepsilon(x))}{(n+1)!}(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$

so evaluating what I have I got $$\frac{2^{x+1}log^3(2)}{6}x^3-3x^2+2x$$

I am stuck at this point I am not sure if I should simplify or evaluate for the interval. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to maximize a smooth function (such as your error)?

Comment: Didn't you forget to derive $f$ in your evaluation? And parentheses.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with maximizing smooth functions we are just learning about lagrange interpolation. as for deriving $f$ i did the triple derivative of $f(x)$ and got the numerator in my evaluation @anderstood

Comment: OK. I don't understand what the error refers to: error of what? If $n=3$, why is your denominator $6$ and not $4!=24$ (maybe it simplified, I did not do the calculation)? I would say the error refers to the distance between the points $(x_i,y_i)$ and the points $(x_i,f(x_i))$. The simplest is probably to compute the three errors.